# flexside2 slide order and shadowbox issues

Tags: lightbox, slide, flexslider, shadowbox

I'm working on a personal website (linked below) and am having trouble integrating a slideshow with lightbox, I'm pretty decent with html and css but not so much with javascript, anyway, I have a slideshow that is working okay, Flexslider2 but for some reason in my code it is displaying whatever is in the last

as the first slide and whatever is the first

as the second slide and the second

as the third slide and so on. Anyway, this wasn't a big deal, until I tried adding in a Lightbox like functionality to the images, regular lightbox was acting really buggy, so I tried shadowbox, which is working better but also has some bugs, most notably it won't display whatever the first image is (the third

), it just links to it like you normally would if you put an image in an  tag, but the subsequent slides work fine, with the exception of being in the wrong order, which comes from the issue of them in fact being out of order.

anyway, I guess my question is does anyone have any experience with flexslider2 slides displaying out of order and how to fix it and a good lightbox like plugin that won't be buggy/or how to fix shadowbox so it will work with flexslide2

here is a link to the offending page of my website: http://www.wesleyonts.com/MySite/portfolio/greenriver.html

if you need anything more specific please let me know and i will try to help as best i can, Thank you